# Vector product on any 3D euclidean vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Take $(V, <\cdot , \cdot >)$ to be an euclidean vector space of dimension 3 with a choice of a basis $\mathcal{B}$ to be positively oriented.

Is there a sensible way to define a generalization of the vector product
$$\land :V\times V\rightarrow V $$
that satisfies the usual properties and only depends on the orientation of $V$ and not on the basis $\mathcal{B}$?

**Possible solution:**
If we define, for any positively oriented orthonormal basis $\mathcal{C} = (e_1,e_2,e_3)$:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3x_ie_i\right)\land_{\mathcal{C}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^3y_ie_i\right) =(x_2y_3-x_3y_2)e_1+(x_3y_1-x_1y_3)e_2+(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)e_3$$
Is it true, then, that $\land_\mathcal{C}=\land_{\mathcal{C}'}$ for every $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}'$ positively oriented orthonormal bases?

Comment: I think that ortogonality and unimodularity (of the vectors of the base) should affect the definition.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Edited the question with the solution that seems like the most obvious to me. Don't know if that would work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual definition of a vector product in three dimensional Euclidean space does not use a notion of a base. Namely, the vector product ${\bf a}\times {\bf b}$ is defined as a vector ${\bf c}$ that is perpendicular (orthogonal) to both ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$, with a direction given by the right-hand rule and a magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram that the vectors span, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) for details.

**Update**. We can use that a Euclidean vector space $V$ of dimension three is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$, but there is a direct proof. Let $\mathcal C’=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $\mathcal C’=(e’_1,e’_2,e’_3)$ be orthonormal basises of $V$. Suppose that for each $i=\{1,2,3\}$ let $e’_i=\sum m_{ij}e_j$ and a $3\times 3$ matrix $M=\|m_{ij}\|$ is orthogonal with positive determinant (that is $1$). Then its [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{adj} M$ is equal to its transposal $M^T$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#3_%C3%97_3_generic_matrix) for a form of an adjugate of a $3\times 3$ generic matrix.

For each $(k,l,n)\in \{(1,2,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2)\}$ we have $$e’_k \land_\mathcal{C’} e’_l= e’_n= m_{n1}e_1+ m_{n2}e_2+ m_{n3}e_3$$
and $$e’_k \land_\mathcal{C} e’_l=(\sum m_{ki}e_i) \land_\mathcal{C} (\sum m_{lj}e_j)=\sum_{i,j} m_{ki} m_{lj} e_i \land_\mathcal{C} e_j=$$ $$(m_{k2} m_{l3}- m_{k3} m_{l2})e_1+ (m_{k3} m_{l1}- m_{k1} m_{l3})e_2+(m_{k1} m_{l2}- m_{k2} m_{l1})e_3.$$  The equality  $$e’_k \land_\mathcal{C’} e’_l=e’_k \land_\mathcal{C} e’_l$$ now follows from the equality $\operatorname{adj} M=M^T$.

Comment: I can't see how I can derive a formal definition from the right hand rule

Comment: @RobertoFaedda By the right hand rule the vector product can be easily computed analytically for pairs of vectors of a given orthonormal basis and then, using the distributivity and linearity of the vector product, for any pair of vectors in term of their representations in the basis, see details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product).

Comment: Although they note that neither distributivity nor linearity of the vector product follows easily from the definition given above, I guess these vector product properties are explained with the pictures in the [next section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties).

Comment: But you do need a orthonormal basis to start with. What I wrote in the question is equivalent to the construction on wikipedia. My question is: if I define two functions as I do above, using two different orthonormal basis, are they actually the same function? I need a proof that they are or an example that shows they're not.

Comment: @RobertoFaedda This is even easier. The product $\land_\mathcal{C}$ which you defined, is a polylinear map $\Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$. So it coincides with the vector product $\times$, defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition), provided these products  coincide on pairs $(f_i, f_j)$, where $(f_1, f_2, f_3)$ is any basis of $\Bbb R^3$. In particular, we can put  $(f_1,f_2,f_3)=\mathcal C$.

Comment: We assume that the orthonormal basis $\mathcal C=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is right-hand oriented, that is $e_1\times e_2=e_3$,  $e_2\times e_3=e_1$, and $e_3\times e_1=e_2$. Using the formula for $\land_\mathcal{C}$, it is easy to check that $e_1\land_\mathcal{C} e_2=e_3$,  $e_2\land_\mathcal{C} e_3=e_1$, and $e_3\land_\mathcal{C} e_1=e_2$, that is the maps $\land_\mathcal{C}$ and $\times$ coincide on $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I'm not working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I haven't defined $\times$ in any way. What I'm trying to do is constructing a surrogate of $\times$ using some (orthonormal) basis $\mathcal{B}$ as I've done above. Then I want to show that if a (orthonormal) basis $\mathcal{C}$ has the same orientation as $\mathcal{B}$ (that is, if the change of basis matrix has positive determinant). It's clear to me that if $\mathcal{C}$ is "right-hand oriented" (as defined by you in the comment above) with respect to $\land_\mathcal{B}$, then $\land_\mathcal{B}=\land_\mathcal{C}$. How do I prove that (continues)

Comment: if $\mathcal{C}=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ has the same orientation as $\mathcal{B}$ (that is if $\det M_{\mathcal{B}\mathcal{C}}(id)>0$), then $\mathcal{C}$ is right-hand oriented with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ (that is $e_i \land_\mathcal{B} e_j = e_k$ for $(i,j,k) \in \{(1,2,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2)\}$)?